# Using 'export' keyword solely for importing into Unit Tests

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, meteor

I'm using Meteor and am writing unit tests for a Collection. I've got Helper methods for the collection in addition to just regular JS functions.

I.e.

```
Collection.helpers({
    helperFn: function () {
        return 'foo';
    }
});

//And in the same file
function bar() {
    return "bar";
}
```

Then in my tests file I have something like

```
import { Collection } from '../collections'
//Use Factory or Stub to create test Document

//This then works just fine and I can assert, etc..
testDoc.helperFn
```

My question is with wanting to test just the regular 'bar' JS function. This isn't a big deal using ES6 classes because then I can just export the whole class and call any function with an instance of it. But with Meteor I'm finding the only way I can access the function is by using the 'export' keyword.

So in my Collection file

```
export function bar ({ return bar; });
```

And now in my test file I'd do something like

```
import { bar } from '../collection'
```

I'd rather not add an export statement for every time I test a new function. Is there any way around this or is it not a big deal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do think that the export/import is the way to go, but to answer the first part of your question: yes, you can fall back to the original scoping of meteor and put these functions in the global scope of meteor as follows:

- do *not* put your files in the `imports/` folder, but into another folder in your project, e.g., `server/`.
- defined the functions as:

  ```
  bar = function() { /* function body */ }
  ```

  These variables are interpreted by meteor as being global to the project, and hence do not need to be imported before use.

That said, there was a reason meteor introduced the `imports/` folder and corresponding export/import paradigm in version 1.3. It avoids polluting the global scope and makes it much easier to see where things are defined.